# Best way to store large amount of data of users

Tags: php, database, linux, file, file-upload

I store files of users in their own name directory something like

```
/username/file01.jpg
/username/file02.mp4
/username/file03.mp3
```

But if more users come and upload more files then this creates problem because this will lead to migration of some or many users to another drive.I choose username directory solution first because i dont want filenames to be mixed. I dont want to change filename too. Also if another user upload same filename then it creates problem ,if the files are stored with original name.

What could be the best way to do this. I have one solution but want to ask community is this the best way .

i will use sequential folders and then hash the file name to some thing very unique and store into the directory. 
What i will do is store the original name of file and username into database and hashvalue of filename which is stored in Disk.

When anyone want to access that file,I will read that file through php either replace the name or will do something at that point so that the file is downloaded as original filename.

I have only this proposed solution in mind. Do you guys have any other better than this one.

Edit:

I use folder system too, and possibly for 2nd way i will use virtual folders.
My database is MongoDB

**Guys all your answers were awesome and really helpful. i wanted to give bounty to everyone, thats why i left it so that community can provide automatically. 
Thanks all for your answers.I really appreciate it.**

Comment: I have found that user ID (unchanging value) is a better method for organizing uploads.  It is harder to navigate by hand (looking at a folder won't tell you who is uploading), but it lets usernames change without breaking the asset folder that corresponds to them.

Comment: @JasonSperske Hi, But how will i handle the users and their files if disk is going to be full and they are continuously uploading .

Comment: Because you are creating a database entry for each file, you could store a "storage volume ID", that you increment each time you run out of space on a storage volume.  When a file is fetched you will get a user ID, File Hash and Storage volume name, which you could combine to retrieve the asset.  I just use Amazon S3 and let them deal with stuff like this however

Comment: @JasonSperske Yeah but in my case. I have my own server to handle files thats why i have to think about this architecture too.BTW users folders in one existing folder is problematic too.

Comment: You might also look into a cloud-based solution like AWS S3 that will automatically handle scaling for you. We use a similar structure (with id's) to manage user files on S3.

Comment: ,i cant use amazon s3 as storing server instead i will prefer my own and would like to implement my own robust architect. :)

Comment: One of my download solutions was to keep everything in folders outside the public directory. On upload, this gets saved to the database with the path, ie: `/home/user/files/1/image.png`, I then create a hash based on the file name and insert ID then save that to the database. Retrieval is just using PHP so we can control what gets downloaded and the download counter. Anything with the same file name, doesn't matter. And definitely look into S3.

Comment: Why don't you want to change the file name ?

Comment: @Baba To create uniqueness, I dont want duplicate file names in dir .and for security reasons too

Comment: Be aware that if you have many (some thousands) users than the root i-node can grow large, so a simple ls command can take long time. So maybe to create subdirectories, like `/a/anakin` etc. could be a good idea.

Comment: The only thing I haven't seen suggested is to store the file under a path/name generated from a hash of the file (sha1 or a longer hash that is unlikely to generate a collision and likely to have a fairly even distribution between hashes). The benefit here is files that generate the same hash (ideally the same file uploaded multiple times) can be linked to multiple users via database. Just curious if there is a reason this wasn't suggested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I handle file metadata on the database and retrive the files with a UUID. What i do is:

1. **Content based identification**

   1. MD5 from file's content
   2. Namespaced UUID:v5 to generate unique identifier based on user's uuid and file's md5.
   3. Custom function to generate path based on 'realname'.
   4. Save on the database: uuid, originalname (the uploaded name), realname (the generated name), filesize, and mime. (optional dateAdded, and md5)
2. **File retrival.**

   1. UUID to retrive metadata.
   2. regenerate filepath based on realname.
   3. Originalname is used to show a familiar name to the user that downloads the file.

I process the file's name assigning it a namespaced UUID as the database primary key, and Generate the path based on User and filename. The precondition is that your user has a uuid assigned to him.  The following code will help you avoid id collisions on the database, and help you identify files by its contents (If you ever need to have a way to spot duplicate content and not necesarily filenames).

```
$fileInfo = pathinfo($_FILE['file']['name']);
$extension = (isset($fileInfo['extension']))?".".$fileInfo['extension']:"";

$md5Name = md5_file($_FILE['file']['tmp_name']); //you could use other hash algorithms if you are so inclined.

$realName = UUID::v5($user->uuid, $md5Name) . $extension; //UUID::v5(namespace, value).
```

I use a function to generate the filepath based on some custom parameteres, you could use $username and $realname. This is helpful if you implement a distributed folder structure which you might have partitioned on file naming scheme, or any custom scheme.

```
function generateBasePath($realname, $customArgsArray){
    //Process Args as your requirements.
    //might as well be  "$FirstThreeCharsFromRealname/"
    //or a checksum that helps you decide which drive/volume/mountpoint to use.
    //like some files on the local disk and some other from an Amazon::S3 mountpoint.
    return $mountpoint.'/'.$generatedPath; 
}
```

As an added bonus this also:

1. helps you maintain a versioned file repository if you add an attribute on the file's record of which file (uuid) it has replaced.
2. create a application Access Control List if you add an attributes of 'owner' and/or 'group'
3. also works on a single folder structure.

Note: I used php's $_FILE as an example of the file source based on this question's tags. It can be from any file source or generated content.

Answer (score 9):

Could you create relational MySQL tables? e.g.:

A `users` table and a `files` table.

Your users table would keep track of everything you are (I assume) already tracking:

`id`, `name`, `email`,  etc.

Then the files table would store something like:

`id`, `fileExtension`,  `fileSize`, `userID` <---- `userID` would be the foreign key pointing to the `id` field in the `files` table.

then when you save your file you could save it as it's `id`.`fileExtension` and use a query to pull the user associated with that file, or all files associated with a user.

e.g.:

```
SELECT users.name, files.id, files.extension
FROM `users`
INNER JOIN `files` on users.id = files.userID;
```

Comment: ,Hi i am not using mysql instead i use mongodb. But this way is also better. Means you are on favour of database handling all the files details.

Answer (score 5):

Since you already use MongoDB, I would suggest checking out GridFS. It's a specification that allows you to store files(even if they are larger than 16mb) into MongoDB collections.

It is scalable, so you'll have no problems if you add another server, it also stores metadata, it is possible to read files in chunks and it also has built in backup functions.

Answer (score 3):

Another tactic is to create a 2-dimensional structure where the first level of directories are the first 2 characters of the username, then the second level is the remaining characters (similar to how Git stores its SHA-1 object IDs). For example:

```
/files/jr/andomuser/456.jpg
```

for user 'jrandomuser'.

Please note that as usernames will likely not be distributed as randomly as SHA-1 values, you may need to add another level later on. Doubt it, though.

Comment: your idea is really impressive. I will think about it. the problem which remains after it is still with data storage in disk. how can that be solved if in case of users and keeping folders.
As amazon s3 dont allow folders.if they did i will have no problem getting their storage because then its their problem how they arrange my files.

Answer (score 3):

I would generate a GUID based on a hash of the filename, Date and Time of the Upload and username for the Filename, save those values, as well as the path to the file in a database for later use. If you generate such a GUID, the filenames can not be guessed.

As example lets take user Daniel Steiner (me) uploads a file called resume.doc on the 23rd of april 2013 at 37 past twelve am to your server. this would give a base value of
Daniel_Steiner+2013/23/04+00:37+resume.doc which then would be as MD5 hash 05c2d2f501e738b930885d991d136f1e. to ensure that the file will be opened in the right programm, we will afterwards add the right file ending and thus will get something like http://link.to/your/site/05c2d2f501e738b930885d991d136f1e.doc If your useraccounts already have a user id, you could add those to the URL, for example, if my User ID would be 123145, the url would be http://link.to/your/site/123145/05c2d2f501e738b930885d991d136f1e.doc

If you save the original filename to the database, you can later also offer a downloadscript that provides the file with its original filename for download, even tough it has another filename on your server.

In case you can use symbolic links, relocating the files on another harddisk shouldn't be a problem either.

If you want to, I could come up with an PHP example as well - shouldn't be too much code.

Answer (score 2):

Since filesystem is a tree, not a graph (faceted classification), its hard to come up with some way for it to easily represent multiple entities, like users, media types, dates, events, image crop types etc. Thats why using relational database is easier - it is convertible to graph.

But since its another level of abstraction, you need to write functions that do low-level synchronization yourself, including avoiding name collisions, long path names, large file count per folder, ease of transfer per-entity, horizontal scaling etc. So it depends how complex your application needs to be

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use following database structure:

[image]

Where `File` table has at least:

[image]

`IDFile` is an `auto_increment` column / primary key.
`UserID` is `nullable` foreign key.

For `FK_File_User` I suggest:

```
ON UPDATE NO ACTION -- IDUser is auto_increment too. No changes need to be tracked.
ON DELETE SET NULL  -- If user deleted, then File is not owned. Might be deleted
                    -- with CRON job or something else.
```

Still, another columns might be added to the `File` table:

1. Actual upload date and time
2. Actual mime-type
3. Actual storage place (for distributed storage systems)
4. Download count (another table might be a better solution)

etc...

***Some benefits:***

1. You don't need to calculate file size, hash, extension or any file meta, because you might obtain it with one database operation.
2. You can obtain statistics for each user of a file count / space used / whatever you wrote to `File` table by single `SELECT ... GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP` statement, and it would be faster, than analysis of actual files, which may be spread across multiple storage devices.
3. You may apply file access permissions for different users. It will cost not significant change of table structures database.

---

I don't consider as an option, that original filenames needed at storage, because of two reasons:

1. File may have name, which not correctly supported by Server OS filesystem, like Cyrillic ones.
2. Two different files may have completely identical names, so one of them might be overwritten by another.

***So, there is a solution:***

1) Rename files when they are uploaded to `IDFile` from `INSERT` into `File` table. It's safe and there are no dublicates.

2) Restore name of the file, when it's needed / downloaded, like:

```
// peform query to "File" table by given ID

list($name, $ext, $size, $md5) = $result->fetch_row();

$result->free();

header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
header('Content-MD5: ' . $md5);
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Connection: close');
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '.' . $ext . '"');

// flush file content
```

3) Actual files may be stored within single directory (because `IDFile` is safe) and `IDUser`-named subdirectory - depends on a situation.

4) As `IDFile` is a direct sequence, if some of files are gone missing, you may obtain their database meta by evaluating missing segments of actual filenames sequence. Then, you may "inform owners", "delete file meta" or both of this actions.

---

*I'm against the idea of storing large actual files in DBMS itself as a binary content*.

DBMS is about data and analysis, it's not a FileSystem, and should never be used in that way, if my humble opinion matters.

Comment: Looks pretty much like my approach ;) And yes, I am against storing Binary files in a Database as well!

Answer (score 1):

You can install a LDAP server. LDAP lookup is very fast since it is highly optimized for heavy read operations. You can even query for data

LDAP organizes the data in a tree like fashion.

You can organize data as following example "user->IP address->folder->file name". This way file could be physically/geographically spread out and you can fetch the location very quickly.

You can query too using standard LDAP query for e.g. get all the list of file for a particular user or get the list of files in the folder etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Mongodb to store the actual filename (eg: myImage.jpg) and other attributes (eg: MIME types), plus `$random-text.jpg` from 2. & 3. below
2. Generate some `$random-text`, eg: `base_convert(mt_rand(), 10, 36)` or `uniqid($username, true);`
3. Physically store the file as `$random-text.jpg` - always good to maintain same extension
4. NOTE: Use `filter_var()` to ensure the input filename doesn't pose security risk to Mongodb.

Amazon S3 is reliable and cheap, be aware of "Eventual Concurrency" with S3.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming users have a unique ID (Primary Key) in the database, if a user with ID 73 uploads a file, save it like this:

"uploads/$userid_$filename.$ext"

For example, 73_resume.doc, 73_myphoto.jpg

Now, when fetching files, use this code:

```
foreach (glob("uploads/$userid_*.*") as $filename) {
    echo $filename;
}
```

This can be combined with hashing solutions (stored in the DB), so that a user who gets a download path as 73_photo.jpg does not randomly try 74_photo.jpg in the browser address bar.